# Please suggest Ionic Application Template

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, mobile-application

I want to develop a mobile application using ionic and angular js, an application just like this one:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vanity.iqbal&hl=en

can I do that with ionic and angular? If so, Please suggest a template for this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on ionic.

And you don't have to use any template but the blank:
`ionic start myApp blank`

Looking at the link you provided, If your concern is the player menu at bottom show on the pictures, You will implement it with a custom Component (might be using a component as a directive). The other stuffs are just Modals (See https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/).

Answer (score 2):

You can choose templates from here 
https://market.ionic.io/themes
You must use Ionic 3 for RTL Nav View.